# removeChild does not work in a setTimeout if there is one element

Tags: javascript, dom, client, settimeout

Here is the code in question:

```
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        holder.appendChild(p);
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (holder.firstChild != null){
                holder.removeChild(holder.firstChild);
            }
        },500);
```

So the expected functionality is that the p goes into the holder, and in 500ms it gets removed.  Yet the p element stays forever, even though I can confirm that the element is not null.  What's going on?

Comment: How do you know that the `<p>` you append is really the first child?

Comment: Why don't you just use `holder.removeChild(p)`?

Comment: Simply use `p.remove()`

Comment: Why not just use `p` in the first place? Inside the `setTimeout` callback: `holder.removeChild(p);`. Or if you want to be paranoid about `p` having already been removed (but what would do that?): `if (p.parentNode) { p.parentNode.removeChild(p); }` (Or on modern browsers, just call `p.remove()`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `firstChild` Node bight well be a `#text` Node

Either use `.firstElementChild` or rather **simply**:
`p.remove()`

- [firstChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild)
- [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild)
- [.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)
- [.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)

Example:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const find = (sel, parent) => (parent ||document).querySelector(sel);
const create = (tag, props) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);

// Task:

const elHolder = find("#holder");
const elP = create("p", {textContent: "I will get removed soon!"});

elHolder.append(elP);
setTimeout(() => {
  elP.remove();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="holder"></div>
```